# How the current moves in the battery and outside the battery?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrons, electric-current, conductors, batteries

Does it move again to the negative terminal or stays at the positive terminal until the electrons all come .so the voltage will.be zero and current flow .I want simple clear explanation because i am confused .when I see a circuit that has two batteries one charging the other so I don't know how to think about it .i guess that electrons come from the negative terminal of the battery of higher emf to the negative terminal of the battery being charged and stay there but if this happen how the current moves to the positive terminal of the battery of higher emf.

Comment: They don't stop, but move again in a full circle. Inside the battery they are moved by chemical forces. In contrast, if a charged capacitor is used as a battery (such as ultracapacitors in hybrid cars), the charges stop at the capacitor and do not cross inside between the terminals.

Comment: how electrons can move again in a full circle  in the picture in the link https://www.google.com.eg/search?q=voltaic+cell&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiF4-KaoYnWAhUPfFAKHcauDfsQ_AUICigB&biw=994&bih=465#imgdii=V-gNyKHdL57VYM:&imgrc=YNWaetxQ5GfDmM:

Comment: these links are useful   http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/miccur.html  .....           http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/leadacid.html

Answer (score 2):

Generally charge (negative) moves from anode to cathode and the chemical reaction in the battery is mediated by a salt bridge (may be different for various battery types). The salt bridge keeps the charge of the total system from separating completely and, in effect, slows down the electro-chemical reaction so that the battery isn't depleted almost immediately. This means that once charge moves through the loop there exists an unbalanced charge distribution in the entire system. The salt bridge supplies ions to the electrolytic solution to maintain neutrality but does not move individual electrons. Without the salt bridge there would be no way for charge to continue to flow and supply power to any connected load. This means that although some electrons may be transported through the salt bridge to move through the loop again the majority complete the loop once and either remain at the cathode, or bind to an atom to become a anion and are absorbed by the salt bridge.

Comment: If your answer is right ,so how the battery is used up and it's voltage decrease If the electrons go back to the negative terminal

Comment: i have learned in chemistry , that any battery is made of negative electrode and positive electrode and an electrolyte .the electrons goes outside the circuit from the negative electrode to the positive electrode. and the current stops when the negative electrode dissolved completetly

Comment: so i deduced that electrons stayed there at the positive electrode

Comment: i have read The chemical reactions in the battery causes a build up of electrons at the anode. This results in an electrical difference between the anode and the cathode. The electrons wants to rearrange themselves to get rid of this difference. But they do this in a certain way. Electrons repel each other and try to go to a place with fewer electrons. In a battery, the only place to go is to the cathode. But, the electrolyte keeps the electrons from going straight from the anode to the cathode within the battery

Comment: I've changed my answer to reflect some new knowledge. The electrolyte supplies the electrons and the salt bridge absorbs and supplies anions and cations if there is an excessive buildup on either side of the battery.

Comment: @Momo, Re, "the electrolyte keeps the electrons from going straight from the anode to the cathode." All battery chemistries in common use today are vulnerable to a phenomenon called [_self discharge_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-discharge). It means, the the battery's charge is slowly depleted even when it is not supplying current to any external circuit. Different chemistries suffer from it in different amounts. Some kinds of battery will keep most of their charge for many years. Others can lose most of it in just a week or two.

Comment: "Salt bridge" brings to mind [19th century batteries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniell_cell#Chemistry) with liquids sloshing in glass jars. What modern battery technology (other than bench-top demos) uses a salt bridge? Some batteries in use today (e.g., the ubiquitous ["alkaline" disposables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkaline_battery)) have a "porous separator" that allows ions through when current flows, but stops chemicals from mixing in bulk; but others (e.g., classic "lead-acid" automotive batteries) just have two electrodes in direct contact with the same electrolyte solution.